# Is it possible to determine if a list operation is thread safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

I am attempting to do a comparison for each element X in a list, ListA, if two properties of X, X.Code and X.Rate, have match the Code and Rate of any element Y in ListB. The current solution uses LINQ and AsParallel to execute these comparisons (time is a factor and each list can contain anywhere from 0 elements to a couple hundred elements each).

So far the AsParallel method seems much faster, however I am not sure that these operations are thread-safe. My understanding is that because this comparison will only be reading values and not modifying them that this should be safe but I am not 100% confident. How can I determine if this operation is thread-safe before unleashing it on my production environment?

Here is the code I am working with:

```
var s1 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
ListA.AsParallel().ForAll(x => x.IsMatching = ListB.AsParallel().Any(y => x.Code== y.Code && x.Rate== y.Rate));
s1.Stop();


var s2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
ListA.ForEach(x => x.IsMatching = ListB.Any(y => x.Code == y.Code && x.Rate== y.Rate));
s2.Stop();
```

Currently each method returns the same result, however the AsParallel() executes in ~1/3 the time as the plain ForEach, so I hope to benefit from that if there is a way to perform this operation safely.

Comment: According to the Thread Safety section of [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), yes.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I am assigning values with x.IsMatching, does that affect your answer @AndrewMorton ?

Comment: Change the "yes" to "not guaranteed". *However*, you are not adding or removing elements, and the assignments do not affect the parts of other elements which are read, so it looks like you are on safe ground.

Comment: Okay, thanks! If you would like to write up an answer out of your comments I would have no problem marking it as the accepted answer

Comment: I would rather not post my comments as an answer because I am not sure enough that it is a good answer. I was hoping someone else would chime in with "Yeah, Andrew's right" or "Andrew is talking rubbish." If you want to, you can write it up as an answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: I was thinking on doing just that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have is thread-safe. The lists are being accessed as read-only, and the implicit synchronization required to implement the parallelized version is sufficient to ensure any writes have been committed. You do modify the elements within the list, but again, the synchronization implicit in the parallel operation, with which the current thread necessarily has to wait on, will ensure any writes to the element objects are visible in the current thread.

That said, the thread safety is irrelevant, because you are doing the whole thing wrong. You are applying a brute force, O(N^2) algorithm to a need that can be addressed using a more elegant and efficient solution, the LINQ `join`:

```
var join = from x in list1
           join y in list2 on new { x.Code, x.Rate } equals new { y.Code, y.Rate }
           select x;

foreach (A a in join)
{
    a.IsMatching = true;
}
```

Your code example didn't include any initialization of sample data. So I can't reproduce your results with any reliability. Indeed, in my test set, where I initialized `list1` and `list2` identically, with each having the same 1000 elements (I simply set `Code` and `Rate` to the element's index in the list, i.e. `0` through `999`), I found the `AsParallel()` version *slower* than the serial version, by a little more than 25% (i.e. 250 iterations of the parallel version took around 2.7 seconds, while 250 iterations of the serial version took about 1.9 seconds).

But neither came close to the `join` version, which completed 250 iterations of that particular test data in about 60 milliseconds, almost 20 times faster than the faster of the other two implementations.

I'm reasonably confident that in spite of my lack of a comparable data set relative to your scenario, that the basic result will still stand, and that you will find the use of the `join` approach far superior to either of the options you've tried so far.